# ARKit 2.0 Bug? "Error initializing VIO"

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

I try to use the ARWorldMap sharing feature.

**EDIT**: I'm using the newest (Beta 3) versions for Xcode, iOS and macOS, downloadable from the [Apple dev site](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

So I make a MultipeerConnectivity Connection between 2 devices. One is scanning until is has a `.mapped` WorldMap which then is being sent to the other device.

Once there and unwrapped, I create a new ARConfiguration and set `configuration.initialWorldMap` to be my received map and run this config by my ARSession.

Shortly thereafter I get this:

```
2018-07-06 15:45:15.453812+0200  [Technique] Error initializing VIO handle (0x116113a00):
2018-07-06 15:45:15.456922+0200  [Session] Session (0x115d22340): did fail with error: Error Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=200 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<redacted>, NSLocalizedFailureReason=<redacted>}
2018-07-06 15:45:15.456995+0200  [Technique] ARWorldTrackingTechnique(0x11a5b2e40) error resetting object detection: ObjectDetectionCallbackNotSet
SessionFailed: World tracking failed.
```

And `session(_:didFailWithError:)` is called.
I can even reproduce this error in [Apples ARMultiuser App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_multiuser_ar_experience) (Radar filed already). A similar error occurs when trying to save and reload the world map.

My code after I receive and unwrap my WorldData:

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()  

configuration.initialWorldMap = worldData.map    // is of type ARWorldMap  

sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

*Notice:*
I'm not asking you to fix Apple's bugs. The reason I came here is simply because I didn't got any feedback not from Apple (yet) and neither from any other Dev. online.

So (just to make sure) all I'm actually asking right now is: **Can you use ARKit 2.0 with the world-sharing feature in the latest beta version?** Do you think this is a valid bug? And can you think of any workarounds?

ANY feedback about the latest beta version of ARKit 2.0 is appreciated ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, no idea how to bypass the VIO (Visual Inertial Odometry, jic someone doesn't know: its basically the AR tracking technique) error.

But I can approve it. I tried it with the sample code from apple you linked and got the same error. I guess you have to wait for Apple to fix it :/

Comment: Nooooo.. well, at least I know for sure now, thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 2):

I also encounted this problem in Beta 3, now I solve this problem by commenting this code:

`configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic`

Answer (score 1):

I know that the demo application you linked worked in Beta 2, but I haven't tried running it in Beta 3 yet if that means anything

Comment: thank you very much.. I actually wasn't sure if I've tried it in Beta 2.... anyway if u r going to test it in Beta3 let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your reference data. This is a known issue with the latest release.
"ARKit: ARReferenceObject and ARWorldMap data generated using iOS 12 beta 2 or earlier isn't compatible with beta 3 or later. Please rescan your objects to generate new ARReferenceObject and ARWorldMap data. (41489820)"
https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/released-ios-12-dev-beta-3-public-beta-2-includes-improved-maps-bug-fixes-security-patches-0185742/

Comment: oh.. good to know, thx.. even tho, I'm not using/loading any 'old' ARWorldMap.. same goes for Apples sample code... I'm creating a new ARWorldMap each time I run my app. So this doesn't apply in my case, does it? ^^